# jenkins pipeline comma delimited strings into parts

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Am struggling to find the way to write jenkins pipeline where, want to achieve :

```
def projectDirectories = [
    "golang-base",
    "java-base",
    "cpp-base",
    "ubuntu-fips",
    "suse-base",
]
def partition(array, size) {
    def partitions = []
    int partitionCount = array.size() / size

    partitionCount.times { partitionNumber ->
        def start = partitionNumber * size 
        def end = start + size - 1
        partitions << array[start..end]    
    }

    if (array.size() % size) partitions << array[partitionCount * size..-1]
    return partitions    
}
def results = partition(projectDirectories, 3)
println "results = ${results}"
```

Above result shows only

```
[[golang-base, java-base], [cpp-base, ubuntu-fips], [suse-base]]
```

Want to split  strings into 2 parts with new lines i.e

```
    golang-base,java-base
    cpp-base,ubuntu-fips
    suse-base
```

So that above can be run in 2 stages parallely. Trying to find out how to achieve to split comma delimited lines into two parts each.

Comment: @NoamHelmer: agreed with you, saw this before, i am trying new lines without "[" and "]"

Comment: thanks @NoamHelmer..researched.
``` 
def results = partition(projectDirectories, 2)
assert results instanceof List  
for(i=0;i<results.size();i++)
{
println results[i];
}
```

returns
```
[golang-base, java-base]
[cpp-base, ubuntu-fips]
[suse-base, golang-base]
[java-base, cpp-base]
[ubuntu-fips, suse-base]
```